# Why can't I use Maltego running on Kali?

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to use Maltego for the first time. But, I am not finding default Infrastructure palette. How do I solve this problem?

Another problem is, I am not able to add transform seed server. How do I solve that?

[image]

And, finally, this is a screenshot from a tutorial available on the internet. 
I cannot find this window in the wizard:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: To the tutorial

Comment: Do you got chlorine? That's the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just wasting my time using ready-made Virtual Machines from [Offensive Security](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/). This thing wasted almost 10 days of my academic life.

I solved my problem by downloading and setting up Kali Linux from [www.kali.org](https://www.kali.org/downloads/). I am using "Kali Linux 64 bit ISO". Maltego is now working.